# Batch processing: GNU-make, Snakemake or what?

Tags: python, bash, batch-processing, gnu-make, snakemake

I need to process a group of files in a directory by passing them to a matlab or a python script.

**For every input file FileName.IN in the directory I need to obtain a output file FileName.OUT.**

It doesn't really matter if the solution is a Python or a bash script.

To achieve my goal I try GNU Make (or Python Snakemake), however I am a bit stuck on it.
It looks like I can say GNU Make to do: 
*" Hey, for every output (target) file FileName.out search the corresponding FileName.IN (prerequisites)"*.

However what I want to do is exactly the opposite, as stated before.

- Is `make` (or `snakemake`) the right choice?
- What else would you suggest?

My `makefile` code looks like this but it doesn't do the job (I am a newbie with GNU make):

```
in_files = *.IN
out_files = *.out
$(out_files) : $(in_files)
    matlab -nosplash -nodesktop -r "a_matlab_function('$<','$@')"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know anything about Snakemake, but in GNU Make you can transform `in_files` to give the `out_files`:

```make
in_files = $(wildcard *.IN)
out_files = $(in_files:.IN=.out)
```

Then you make a dummy target that depends on all the outputs:

```make
all: $(out_files)
.PHONY: all
```

And finally a rule to create one output from one input:

```make
%.out: %.IN
    matlab -nosplash -nodesktop -r "a_matlab_function('$<','$@')"
```

Comment: This is *much* better than the _bash_ script above. It checks return values as it goes. You can run it a second time and it will only re-convert files that have changed. It will use _all_ your CPUs is you ask _make_ nicely.

Comment: It works fine, thanks a lot.

Can you explain the role of PHONY target in this case? The make manual it's not really useful for that.

Also I don't understand the way the variables (in_files and out_files) are being used: they are defined but not used in the rule. 
How can the rule put the correct filename, then?

Comment: To understand the pattern rules see: https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Pattern-Intro.html  I'm not sure what you mean by the make manual not being useful but `.PHONY` basically tells make that this target (here, `all`) doesn't represent a real file on the disk, it's just a "fake" target that can be used to cause other targets to be built (via its prerequisites list).

Comment: `.PHONY` is used to indicate that `all` [is not a file to be re-made](/a/2145605).  Instead, its rules will be run even if file called `all` exists and is older than the dependencies.

Comment: @Robyc: `in_files` is used only to initialise `out_files` - you could eliminate it by using `out_files = $(subst .IN,.out,$(wildcard *.IN))` if you want.  `make all` needs to make every file in `out_files` - these all end in `.out` so they match the `%.out` rule.  Does that make sense?

Comment: @TobySpeight @MadScientist thanks. 
The part on the variable name substitution is now clear.
The pattern substitution is also clear. Let me see if everything else is clear.
So `make all` **always** runs because it has been declared as `.PHONY`.
`all` is the default goal of the makefile and hence the `out_files` are forced to be updated, if necessary.
It looks like make doesn't accept `%.out` as the **default goal**, so the makefile doesn't work if I don't declare the target `all`.

Comment: So to me looks like declaring `all: $(out_files)` is needed in order to expand the pattern %. Is that correct?

Comment: In a way - the `all: $(out_files)` dependency just provides a convenient way of saying that you want every output to be made.  The pattern rule `%.out: %.IN` is considered for every target that ends in `.out`.  So if you invoke `make foo.out`, that rule will be matched, and `foo.out` will be made (if necessary) from `foo.IN`.  You're right that a pattern rule cannot be a default goal (that wouldn't make any sense, because Make needs to be told to produce one or more specific files (or phony targets).  BTW, `all` is a conventional name for the default target, but you could use any legal name.

Answer (score 2):

I think you just want a `bash` for loop:

```
for f in *.IN; do
   out=${f%IN}OUT                # Work out name of output file
   echo IN:"$f"                  # Show input file to user
   echo OUT:"$out"               # Show output file to user
   matlab <options> "$f" "$out"  # Run Matlab
done
```

So, if I have these files:

```
ls *IN

aThird.IN   
another one.IN
b.IN
```

I'll get this:

```
IN:aThird.IN
OUT:aThird.OUT
IN:another one.IN
OUT:another one.OUT
IN:b.IN
OUT:b.OUT
```

Or, as a one-liner:

```
for f in *.IN; do out=${f%IN}OUT; matlab ... "$f" ... "$out"; done
```

**Notes**:

Although your question suggests using **make**, there is no certain indication whether you always expect to run all jobs, or whether sometimes some jobs do not need running - presumably because the output files already exist and it is not necessary to run them. If you don't want all the jobs run every time, you will probably be better off with **make**.

Also, if Matlab can run parallel instances, the **GNU Parallel** syntax is nice for things like this:

```
parallel --dry-run matlab {} {.}.OUT ::: *IN
```

**Output**

```
matlab another\ one.IN another\ one.OUT
matlab aThird.IN aThird.OUT
matlab b.IN b.OUT
```

Here, the `--dry-run` shows you the commands that would be run, though it currently does not run anything.

Comment: You'll probably want to `test "$in" -nt "$out"` to avoid rebuilding outputs whose inputs haven't changed.

Comment: I'd suggest quoting the expansions going into your `echo`s, just to be showcasing good practices consistently.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. 
Yes it's not necessary to do again jobs if the input file doesn't change.

Btw what I think it's really nice about makefiles is that the code looks pretty clean.